# Choosing image size for react native app

Tags: image, react-native

I need some fullscreen images for a react native app. What size should I stick to? Should I add multiple images for different resolutions, like one of width 320, one of width 480, 720, 920, 1280, 1920 etc and choose them according to `Dimensions.get` output? If so, which sizes should I include? Or maybe I don't need that much images and sticking to one with average resolution is still fine? What are best practices to choose image size?

Answer (score 2):

the size of the images to serve depends on the data you get from `Dimensions`, `pixelRatio` and `NetInfo`.

Let's say regular iPhone width is 320. If you get that and `pixelRatio` is 2, it makes sense to serve 720 if you want the images to be sharp. That is the math to base the sizing upon.

On top of that it makes sense to check `NetInfo.isConnectionExpensive()` and downgrade the quality if the network isn't appropriate.

I think a good way to handle this is to have 3-4 base image sizes - small, medium, large, extraLarge (to cover tablets) and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation describes, that you can place your Image where you want in your JS-Structure and you can use @2 and @3 suffix to support different Pixel-Densities, if you use static resources: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources

The rest will be handled by reactnative (even like only importing images are really needed.

But I also wonder what are a good starting-point to provide good resolutions. 
Maybe anybody has an additional suggestion, wich resolution to start with on default density, and which to use for @2 and @3 suffixes.